# Why does Typescript + VS Code show type "any" with InstanceType?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I can't repro this on TS Playground. I have a method that returns an instance:

```
class Base {
  static selectOne<T extends typeof Base>(this: T): InstanceType<T> {}
}

class Foo extends Base {}
class Bar extends Base {}
```

This usually works fine with VS Code IntelliSense, e.g.:

```
const foo = Foo.selectOne(); // foo is type "Foo"
```

However, if I have a union of classes, it stops working:

```
const foo = (Foo as typeof Foo | typeof Bar).selectOne(); // foo is type "any"
```

This example works in [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ0PQgFzNglsFgiAsNgPIB2CAPACrQIAe2CVAJjNgJ4AOCAPYAzOIgB8ACmwALfBABc0egEolASSo4wVYAnr869cSgC%20qc6lCQYAMUGCmrdlzEQkyc9ahiATk7ZOGHh3M1QrQS1saGEHaABeaEl7R0hoXgERaBToAB90wyz4XxUAOndScmoESRUAblQgA), it shows `Foo | Bar`, so there's probably something weird with my classes. As a workaround, I needed to add the instance type to the class:

```
class Base {
  static selectOne<T extends typeof Base>(this: T): T['instanceType'] {}
  static instanceType: Base;
}

class Foo extends Base {
  static instanceType: Foo;
}
class Bar extends Base {
  static instanceType: Bar;
}
```

What are some possible reasons why `InstanceType` returns `any`? I already spent several days trying to debug this. I can't share a reproducible example because there's hundreds of files.

Base tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "strict": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": false,
    "types": ["node"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules",
    "./build",
  ],
}
```

Comment: If it works in the playground, then it works in Typescript. What version of typescript are you using? What does your `tsconfig.json` look like?

Comment: I can't paste hundreds of files into TS Playground, so I don't know if it works there. It's TS 4.6.4. I added the base tsconfig.json

Comment: So in your code base you paste this _exact_ example: https://tsplay.dev/mAy4Qm then the type for `foo` is `any`? If that example pulls in no other code it should work as you expect. If the problem is in code you haven't posted, then we dont have much to go on.

Comment: My question is "What are some possible reasons why InstanceType returns any?", not "look at my code"